# Multi-Core CPU training on Keras

Tags: keras, training

I want to train models on a machine with multi-cores, I know training on GPU is better but I only have access now on CPU.
Which parameters should I set using keras.models.Model.fit to utilize all cores?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893161/why-does-tensorflow-only-find-one-cpu-device-despite-having-multiple-cores) answer your question?

Comment: and [this](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/194877)